# JQuery: find all TD's Next or greater than me in current row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Table looks like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to do a poor mans version of fill right and I don't want to pollute the obj with classes.

Pretty sure I can do something like this.

```
// e is the current input on blur
Function FillRight(e){

//  need to get all inputs in current row only
e.nextAll('input').each(function (i, val) {
  $(this).val(e.val());
});

}
```

tnx in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect selector for targeting other input elements in table. use:

```
e.parent().siblings().find('input').each(function (i, val) {
  $(this).val(e.val());
});
```

or

```
e.closest('table').find('input').not(e).each(function (i, val) {
  $(this).val(e.val());
});
```

Comment: this gets me really close but it updates all siblings.  Left and right of (e).

Comment: use `e.parent().nextAll().find('input').each(function (i, val) {
  $(this).val(e.val());});`

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily do something like this, checking for the next element past the one you passed, and then keep assigning the next to e until there are no next ones left.

```
Function FillRight(e){
    while(e.next().length){
        e = e.next();
        // You could search for a child element here, like your input.
        e.children("input");
    }
}
```

Or you could even look for a specific child element is there in the while loop, if you want to.